# Text disappearing on Card

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to make a flashcard app to remember basics about Javascript.

I am able to display the cards as they should, but if the text on the back of the card is longer than the front of the card, the text disappears and then occasionally flashes on hover.

Here is what happens: https://agitated-shaw-22f47c.netlify.app/

The first card is the problem, since it's short text on front causing it to glitch, but the second card works as it should.

Here is my github repo: https://github.com/SillasPoulsen/flashcard

This is the css I have:

```
  background-color: #c8d0d2;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 1rem 2rem;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0 1.5rem;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.form-group {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0.5rem;
}

.form-group > label {
  color: #777;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  margin-bottom: 0.25rem;
}

.btn {
  background-color: hsl(200, 100%, 50%);
  color: white;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  border-radius: 0.3em;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: hsl(200, 100%, 40%);
}

.card-grid {
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  gap: 1rem;
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background-color: white;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: 150ms;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(var(--rotate-y, 0))
    translateY(var(--translate-y, 0));
}

.card:hover {
  --translate-y: -2px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.card.flip {
  --rotate-y: 180deg;
}

.card .front {
  left: 0;
}

.card .front,
.card .back {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 1rem;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.card .back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flashcard-options {
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
}

.flashcard-option {
  margin-top: 0.25rem;
  color: #555;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
}

.flashcard-option:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

This is my react code for the component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

export default function Flashcard({ flashcard }) {
  const [flip, setFlip] = useState(false);
  const [height, setHeight] = useState("initial");

  const frontEl = useRef();
  const backEl = useRef();

  function setMaxHeight() {
    const frontHeight = frontEl.current.getBoundingClientRect().height;
    const backHeight = backEl.current.getBoundingClientRect().height;
    setHeight(Math.max(frontHeight, backHeight, 100));
  }

  useEffect(setMaxHeight, [flashcard.question, flashcard.answer]);
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("resize", setMaxHeight);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", setMaxHeight);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div
      className={`card ${flip ? "flip" : ""}`}
      style={{ height: height }}
      onClick={() => setFlip(!flip)}
    >
      <div className="front" ref={frontEl}>
        <p>{flashcard.question}</p>
      </div>
      <div className="back" ref={backEl}>
        <p>{flashcard.answer}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I just had a look and it seems to be working okay. I can't see any of the flashing/glitching issues you mention. What browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome: Version 96.0.4664.110 (Official Build) (x86_64)

Comment: It's an issue with your css, there is a css property called fit-content, try putting it somewhere in your card's css, it should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is no glitch if you are using "Google Chrome" but with "Mozilla" I do see glitch. My guess there is nothing wrong with your code it is just Browser settings.

You can try to turn off hardware acceleration within Mozilla Firefox:

- Start Mozilla Firefox.
- Select Tools > Options > Advanced > General.
- Uncheck Use hardware acceleration when available.

That should help.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I am using Google Chrome: Version 96.0.4664.110 (Official Build) (x86_64)